# Store value and reuse it in javascript oops

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have currently 3 div and it can be more than three, Every div has one anchor tag, anchor tag have click functionality to open `UL` within the same parent. what I want is I can open `UL` and close them without effecting other one. I have made a function with oops concept but it is not working as I want. It takes two click for next anchor tag. Can it be done by oops logic or we have to choose another way. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kbbgvts/)

```
$(function(){

    function get(){
        this.a=1;
        this.show= function(a){     
            $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown()
        };
        this.hide= function(a){
            $(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp()
        }
    }

    var n= new get();
    $('a').click(function(){
        if(n.a){
            n.show.call(this)
            n.a=0;
        }
        else{
            n.hide.call(this)
            n.a=1;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: That fiddle link is empty.

Comment: Did you mean for your JSFiddle link to just go to the JSFiddle site or have you set up a fiddle to view this code on?

Comment: I have edit fiddle link which is http://jsfiddle.net/2kbbgvts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want with:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle()
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kbbgvts/1/

edit:
In addition, one way to do this the way you were trying to do it is with closures:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var anchor = $(this);
    var shown = false;
    function toggle(){
        if(shown) anchor.parent().find('ul').slideUp()
        else $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown()
        shown = !shown;
    }
    anchor.click(toggle);
});
```

This is just to demonstrate *how* something like this can be done. Using slideToggle and fadeToggle is much more straightforward in this case.
http://jsfiddle.net/2kbbgvts/2/

Comment: thank for answering the question, you answer is working fine but when we use like fadeIn and fadeOut instead of slideToggle, So how we mange it

Comment: This is the way i'd do it as well.  Or maybe using `$('a').on('click', function(){` instead of `$('a').click(function(){` for the first line - just personal preference.

Comment: For toggling a fade just change `slideToggle` with `fadeToggle`.  See: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/